# Is it possible join a lot of files in Apache Flume?

Tags: hadoop, flume

Our server receive a lot of files every moment. Size of files is pretty small. Around 10 MB. Our management want to make Hadoop cluster for analysis and storage of these files. But it is not effective to storage small files in hadoop. Is it any options in hadoop or in Flume to join (make one big file) this files?
Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: What is the source of data? Flume and Nifi can both be used to merge file contents, yes... Or you can just land the small files, then use Pig or Spark to make bigger ones from those

Answer (score 0):

Here's what comes to my mind:
1) Use Flume's "Spooling Directory Source". This source lets you ingest data by placing files to be ingested into a “spooling” directory on disk.
Write your files to that directory.

2) Use whichever channel you want for Flume: "memory" or "File". Both have advantages and disadvantages.

3) Use HDFS Sink to write to HDFS.

The "spooling directory source" will rename the file once ingested (or optionally delete). The data also survives crash or restart.
Here's the documentation:
https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source

Comment: You can plug-in the parsing logic for the files.